# oracle sql 12 how to display the number of current account is not displaying , any suggestions please?the query and table below

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
select distinct b.brid, 
    (select count(1) from account a 
      where a.brid= b.brid
      and a.acctype='current'
      ) as num_accounts,
    b.baddress.street, b.baddress.city, b.baddress.p_code 
from branch b;
```

the table should display the number of current account,but nothing is showing

[image]

Comment: What do your tables look like?  Are you getting an error?  What do you mean "nothing is showing"?

Answer (score 1):

Query you posted doesn't make sense. What is `b.baddress.street`? The way you put it,

- `b` is user
- `baddress` is table
- `street` is column

but what is `b.brid`, then?

You posted screenshot of ... what? Desired result? Can't be as it displays 2 columns, while query returns 5 of them.

---

Anyway: this is how it might be done. Try to adjust it to your table(s). Mind letter case (is it really `'current'`? Maybe `'CURRENT'`? Or ...?)

```
  SELECT b.brid,
         COUNT (*) num_accounts,
         b.street,
         b.city,
         b.p_code
    FROM branch b JOIN account a ON a.brid = b.brid
   WHERE a.acctype = 'current'
GROUP BY b.brid,
         b.street,
         b.city,
         b.p_code;
```

Comment: Maybe `baddress` is a user-defined type? Addresses are commonly employed in examples of using UDTs to define columns in OR tables.

Comment: Maybe it is, @APC. Good catch!

Comment: brid is the branch id.Will try with your query if it will work.Thanks @Littlefoot

Comment: @Littlefoot i made a bit modification and it worked.Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery for this purpose:

```
select b.*,  -- or whatever columns you want
       (select count(1) 
        from account a 
        where a.brid = b.brid and a.acctype = 'current'
       ) as num_accounts
from branch b;
```

In other words, you appear to have an error in how your are referencing columns in `b`, but the actual part of the query that does the count is correct.

Comment: thanks ,what if i want to find the highest current from each branch displaying customers name?

Comment: @May . . . Then you would have a different question.  And that should be asked as a *new* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: ,i have reached my limit,so i have to wait for a couple of days.